# Show that $\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{12} \right) > \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Show that $\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{12} \right) > \frac{1}{4}$

I'm trying to show this, but I can't seem to get it right. Graphically this equality seems to be intuitive, but I can't see how to prove it.

I tried setting $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=x$ and looking at the way that $f(x)$ decreases along $(0,\pi)$ by looking at its second derivative and comparing that to $g(x)$, but it didn't seem to work that way. Although I was close, it doesn't seem like to me that that method will work. Does anyone have a better way (preferably one that doesn't involve having to physically draw graphs?)

Comment: It's actually easy to compute $\sin(\pi/12)$ directly.

Comment: Can you use $\sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: There's the double-angle formula. And $\cos \frac{\pi}{12} < 1$ ain't hard.

Comment: Well, you're on to something. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If one can use $\sin \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$, the double-angle formula gives

$$\sin \frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{6}}{2\cos \frac{\pi}{12}} = \frac{1}{4\cos \frac{\pi}{12}},$$

and all that remains is to argue that $0 < \cos \frac{\pi}{12} < 1$.

Comment: This is great! May I ask how you thought of going from the first step to the second one? Seems quite ingenious!

Comment: I'm not sure what you consider the first and second step, so I'll chat a little ;) The basic strategy is to use things one knows. What I know about the trigonometric functions are primarily the values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ at $0, \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{2}$ (and what follows immediately from those, like at $k\pi$), and the addition formulae for sine and cosine (and the derivatives, but these play no role here, and a couple of other things that also aren't pertinent). Now it doesn't take much to see $\frac{\pi}{12} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{\pi}{6}$, so one can look…

Comment: at the double angle formulae to see what they give. The one for the sine is nicer here since it's a product, so use $\sin \frac{\pi}{6} = 2\sin \frac{\pi}{12}\cos \frac{\pi}{12}$. Rearranging it shows we need $\frac{1}{\cos \frac{\pi}{12}} > 1$.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know, great explanation! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{12}} = \frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4} = \frac14 \frac1{2+\sqrt{3}} \gt \frac1{16}$$

because $2 \gt \sqrt{3}$.  The result follows.

Comment: Why does $\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{12}} = \frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}$? Is the only way to know this to compute this by triangles?

Comment: $$\sin^2 x = \frac{1 - \cos 2x}{2}$$

Comment: @SkeletonBow haha, power-reducing formula from calculus?

Answer (score 1):

Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html, $$\sin\dfrac\pi6-\sin\dfrac\pi{12}=\cdots>0$$ as sine,cosine ratios are positive in the first quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   \cos\dfrac{\pi}{12} &<1 \\
   \sin \dfrac{\pi}{12} \cos\dfrac{\pi}{12}&<\sin \dfrac{\pi}{12} \\
   \frac 12\left(2\sin \dfrac{\pi}{12} \cos \dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)
      &<\sin \dfrac{\pi}{12} \\
   \frac 12\sin \dfrac{\pi}{6}&<\sin \dfrac{\pi}{12} \\
   \frac{1}{4}&<\sin \dfrac{\pi}{12} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Or** , you could try this:

$$ \frac {\pi}{12} = \frac {\pi}{4} -\frac {\pi}{6}$$

using the trig identity,
$$ sin(x + y) = sin(x)cos(y) + sin(y)cos(x)$$
$$ sin(\frac {\pi}{4} + \frac {-\pi}{6}) = sin(\frac {\pi}{4})cos(\frac {-\pi}{6}) +sin(\frac {-\pi}{6})cos(\frac {\pi}{4})$$
$$\implies sin(\frac {\pi}{12})  = \frac {\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

It is obvious that $\sqrt{3} < \sqrt{2}+1 \implies  \frac {\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{4} < \frac{1}{4}$.